# Can't copy MS Word document to my app from iOS Word app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ms-word

I want to open a Word file in my app's delegate function with

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options
```

and by adding to my Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>doc</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>AppIcon.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft doc</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

When I open an email in Google Inbox app with a Word document attached I see my app in the Document Interaction Controller and a copy of the Word file is sent to the delegate function.

But when I open de Document Interaction Controller in the iOS Word app via tapping the "..." behind the Word file in the list of recent files and then: "share" > "send copy" > "send with another app" my app is NOT visible in the Document Interaction Controller.

What should I do more or different to see my app in the Document Interaction Controller of an iOS Word App to edit the Word file in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have to mention in the Info.plist that the LSItemContentTypes conforms to **org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document** format

so the Info.plist will become:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>doc</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>AppIcon.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Microsoft Word</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
          <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```